# I want to create custom azure pipeline task for testing tool

Tags: azure-pipelines

I want to use testing tool in azure pipeline hence I want to create custom task for the same.
Testing tool has few Jar's and run.bat file hence I have created task.json file as below and assumed no need to create index.tas file.
Please suggest

```
{
    "$schema": "",
    "id": "96b1719d-313a-4ac8-a959-6f28cc95dbfd",
    "name": "CITSExecution",
    "friendlyName": "CITS Test Execution",
    "description": "Execute CITS Test",
    "helpMarkDown": "Execute CITS Test using input parameters",
    "category": "Test",
    "visibility": [ "Build", "Release" ],
    "author": "",
    "version": {
        "Major": 0,
        "Minor": 1,
        "Patch": 0
    },
    "instanceNameFormat": "CITS Test Execution",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "JarFiles",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "CITS Test",
            "defaultValue": "-cp;D:\\CITS\\cognizant-intelligent-test-scripter-1.2-setup\\cognizant-intelligent-test-scripter-1.2\\lib\\cognizant-intelligent-test-scripter-engine-1.2.jar",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": ""
        }
    ],
    "execution": {
        ".bat": {
            "target": "D:\\CITS\\cognizant-intelligent-test-scripter-1.2-setup\\cognizant-intelligent-test-scripter-1.2\\Run.bat"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can refer to this [blog](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/dev-ops-vsts-custom-build-task-extension) on creating custom task in vsts

Comment: You can put .bat in the execution. you should read the docs.